# Odd object type change in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Can someone tell me why this

```
Details user=(Details) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
```

sometimes returns `Object` and sometimes `String`?

I've tested if user is logged in with

```
System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated());
```

It prints true.

Comment: what OBject? what string? Does it fail with ClassCastException? Which exactly returns that. the question is unclear.

Comment: Object. Yes it fails with that.

Answer (score 2):

The object obtained in `getDetails()` is really the place for *extra* information about the authentication that took place, that's why it is an `Object` that might contain just about anything. Though some like Stephen C might hate it, I think it's brilliant because it allows you store information about *how* the user logged in as well as the usual *who* logged in. For example we use it to record which of our subdomains the user logged in on, which is critical information for our application.

I think that `getDetails()` will typically return a `WebAuthenticationDetails` object if the user logged in with a web form. I can't remember exactly what causes it to return a string, but I suspect it is for anonymous users.

It might sound confusing, but there is no need to look at `getDetails()` in basic use of Spring Security. `getDetails()` doesn't tell you any information about who is logged in or what they are allowed to do, so you can safely ignore it — unless your application (like mine) needs to know *how* as well as *who* logged in.

Comment: I actually would need getPrincipal, but it is the same String problem. Can you tell me why is this?

Answer (score 2):

Existing authentication methodologies involve three basic “factors”:

- Something the user knows (e.g.,
  password, PIN); [Authentication.getCredentials()]
- Something the user has (e.g., ID, ATM
  card, smart card); [Authentication.getPrincipal()] and
- Something the user is (e.g.,
  biometric characteristic, such as a
  fingerprint). [Authentication.getDetails()]

It makes perfect sense that designers chose to have all three (`Credentials`, `Principal` and `Details`) as `Object` in `Authentication` interface.

In spring security, an `AuthenticationProvider` can set details in successful authentication. The default `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` copies the details received in authentication request to the successful authentication. Assuming that none of the authentication providers is putting String in details, we should check Filters to see if any string is being set in details of authentcation request.

Answer (score 1):

The `Authentication.getDetails()` method is an abomination.  The `Authentication` interface says that it returns an `Object` and different implementations return widely varying details objects.

Why did they do this?

My guess is because the designers thought it would unduly restrict peoples' ability to support site-specific implementation details.  Or maybe they just put off doing it properly, and then discovered it was too late.

The end result is that if your site uses multiple authentication / authorization mechanisms, extracting and using user details is a right pain in the butt.

Answer (score 0):

As @gutch says, from the javadoc of `getDetails()`

Stores additional details about the authentication request. These might be an IP address, certificate serial number etc.

As for `getPrincipal()`

In the case of an authentication request with username and password, this would be the username.

The `AuthenticationManager` implementation will often return an `Authentication` containing
richer information as the principal for use by the application. Many of the authentication providers will create a `UserDetails` object as the principal.

So what is returned is based on who returns it!

Answer (score 0):

String will be usually returned when you grant resource access to anonymous user. You configuration should look something like this,

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
```

Check here more on anonymous authentication here,
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html

If you are using auto configuration and not configuring anonymous user attributes, org.springframework.security.config.http.AuthenticationConfigBuilder takes care of this. In this case, the anonymous user name will be 'anonymousUser' and 'ROLE_ANONYMOUS' will be granted authority.